# Wifi-Direct : How to communication between two SoftAP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtual-wifi

My question is simple, but could not find answer till now.

I want to create a mess network using SoftAPs created over mobile devices. To achieve this, my device which are hosting SoftAP needs to be interconnected. Is this possible ? If not then is there any alternative approach by which i can make it happen.

Only limitation is, I don't want to use Cloud(INTERNET) OR Relay server.